# Azure Application Insights firewall rules

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm having some troubles sending telemetry data of my web application because of firewall rules are configured by IP, and the thing is that the IP for the App Insights are constantly changing (As far as I know this is because the App Insights services are behind a CDN so the IP depends on where the requests come from).

The question is if somebody knows if there is an IP range, or a lists of IPs that the IT people of my client could use to configure the firewall in order to keep allowing the telemetry traffic.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who ends up here in the future, they do have a list of ip address used by application insights available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses

There are a ton more on the documentation page but here are the main telemetry IP's it uses:

> - 40.114.241.141
> - 104.45.136.42
> - 40.84.189.107
> - 168.63.242.221
> - 52.167.221.184
> - 52.169.64.244
>
> All on port 443

Answer (score 1):

I asked about this, and it does not appear that the specific IP addresses are publicly shared at this time.

The recommendation would be, if possible, to filter by host name (dc.services.visualstudio.com).

Comment: Thank you @tomasr  Unfortunately IT people needs the IP address, seems it is for performance reasons on the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to static IPs is on the team's backlog, but no specific ETA can be given at this point. We'll update this thread once we have static IPs with ranges that we can share.